# Subnetting: correct address for router interface?

Tags: subnet

This is a portion of a larger network, but I've simplified it for the sake of the question.

[Here is the network](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40925765/KTIIT/LAN%20Kursinis/SKMBT_C22015061815580-rotated.pdf).

Adresses in it are as follows:

```
Server: 192.168.0.97/30
Router to server IF0: 192.168.0.98/30
Network with 8 pcs: 172.16.40.144/28
The 8th pc: 172.16.40.152/28
Router to the network with 8 pcs IF1: 172.16.40.158/28
```

Now, I've been told that last one is incorrect, but I can't figure out why. As far as I understand it, it should be the last available adress of the .144 network, thus .158

The teacher figured out it was wrong  [looking at this table](http://exploit.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/subnetting.png).

But looking at it now I can't find his reason.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: this is a programming forum not a network forum

Comment: but there are other subnetting questions here...

Answer (score 0):

The last 4 bits of the 0th pc on the network would be 0000, which converts to 172.168.40.144. The last 4 bits of the highest possible value is 1111, which converts to 172.168.40.159.  I'm not sure if that would be the broadcast address though.

Comment: Shouldn't the broadcast adress be left untouched? [This](https://www.countryipblocks.net/identifying-the-network-and-broadcast-address-of-a-subnet) says _Broadcast Address: An IP Address that allows information to be sent to all machines on a given subnet rather than a specific machine. (See RFCs: 826, 919, 922, 947, 1027, 1770, 3021)._  I tried this .159 adress on Riverbed modeller, and it won't work.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Just wanted to make sure that your prof took this into account.